# toString() in POJO Class

Tags: java, tostring, pojo, apache-stringutils

Is it required to add toString() in all the POJO classes?

Its kind of a very basic question but I am worried about writing a piece of code in each n every POJO classes.

I have followed many java sources and I found a common things in those POJO classes-

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return StringUtil.toDetailString(this);
    }
```

Is it required for serialisation or helps in performance improvement or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my experience I prefer to add a `toString()` method in all POJO classes because it helps if you want to print the current state of an instance, using a logging framework or not.

The default `toString()` method outputs a string formed from:

`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`.

That is not useful 99.8% of the time. Usually you want to read the value of your class attributes. For that you need to override `toString()`.

You never know when you want to see its state outside of a debugging framework.

If you/someone else logs your instance to see what it contains, if you don't override the `toString()` the output will only be the name and hash; that is not very informative.

The performance aspect is not influenced at all, neither is serialization (using a serious framework) as far as I know of.

I recommend using the *source generation* feature of your IDE to generate `toString()` methods. It is fast and gives you more control.

Comment: To know current state of the instance will be required only in Debug mode or in Loggers. I accept it. But how does it differ from Object.toString()?

Comment: The default `toString()` implementation available in the `Object` class gives you a string formed from `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` and that is not useful 99.8% of the time. Usually you want to output the value of some attributes of your class.

Comment: Updated the answer to include that comment too. Glad I could help !

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you're going to use the POJO for. In general, it's certainly not required. `toString()` is not used in default Java binary serialization, although it may be used by *some* serialization frameworks. (I'm not aware of any that do this, but it's far from impossible.)

There's no performance benefit either.

There *is* potentially a diagnostic benefit though - that's the primary use of `toString()` - to get a string representation for diagnostic purposes, whether in a debugger or when logging. In some cases you may also wish to rely on `toString()` for non-diagnostic purposes, but you usually know about that when you do it... and normally such an implementation wouldn't just be `StringUtil.toDetailString` - that sounds like it's just going to produce something possibly-JSON-like which is more aimed at developers than anything else.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thanks Jon.

Comment: So, toString() is present in Object class. And above code chunk is changing definition of the default toString() implementation. And it can be modified according to our requirement anytime when we would like to do so. Am I going right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to override `toString` if you are happy with the default implementation inherited from `Object`. The default basically gives you the class name and a hash value.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not "required" to have toString in all Pojo classes. If there is no toString method in your pojo, then the toString of the super class (Object) will be invoked. Because end of the day, all your classes extend Object class.

here is the javadoc for the Object-toString()
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

> **public String toString()**
>   Returns a string representation of the object.
>   In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually
>   represents" this object. The result should be a concise but
>   informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is
>   recommended that all subclasses override this method.  The toString
>   method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the
>   class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@',
>   and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
>   object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the
>   value of:
>
> *getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())* 
>   **Returns:** a string representation of the object.